# How do you put 2 commands in the same command block in 1.12 on PC/Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know how to put 2 commands in the same command block, but I don't know how. I think I need to use /execute, but that might not work. If you have ideas, please tell me. That would be greatly appreciated for me and other people.

Comment: Please do not say I need to use 2 command blocks.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to accomplish?  The `/execute` command is the only command that takes a second command as a parameter, but you can also use `/setblock` to create a second command block that has a different command, or you could `/summon` a command block falling sand entity that has other command block falling sand entities as passengers.  You can also call a function from a command block that runs a whole bunch of commands.

Comment: What two commands are you trying to use?  What are you trying to accomplish with them?  What have you tried already?  Specific questions are more likely to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @MBraedley How do you turn the falling sand into command blocks though?

Comment: @fishfinboy1 You are right /execute allows you to have 2 commands in 1 command block but the /execute command counts as one of those commands for instance the command /execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass 0 /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:diamond_block sets a diamond block under the player when he steps on grass but /execute is used mainly for detecting when the player touches something and then running a command when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.mcfunction` file for your world

They allow for multiple command in a single command block.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to bear bad news but you have to use 2 command blocks

Comment: Wait but for /execute you can /execute (player name) (coordinator